# Calculating time using javascript and automaticailly submitting form to the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

THIS IS A DISCUSSION. I am creating a quiz application, using php. The quiz run for 12 minutes. I want my application to be able to detect when a user login and start calculating the time, immediately it is 12 minutes I want the form to submit automatically if the user is not done. I know i can not do this with php because it server side but i can archive this with javascript and i am not a pro in javascript. Can someone please direct me on how to go about this or point me to the right tutorial. Please. (I hope my question is clear enough)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because discussions are off topic.

Comment: I already got what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So preety much what the code below does is that when the form is submited, i just set an interval. The timer's interval is millisecond will increast the var milliSecond. So that var calculates how much MilliSeconds the user spent.

```
 $(form).on('submit', function(){
     var milliSecond = 0;
     setInterval(function(){
       milliSecond++;
     }, 1)
    })
```

Im sure you can check if the form is submited. So when the form is submitted you can execute the code below:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
            display.textContent = "Done!"
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<span id="time">05:00</span> minutes left!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... You solved and changed my problem. Now am thinking which code should i use  because I got two wonderful answers that answered my question perfectly. Thank you @Bogale

Comment: @Ukor i wasnt here 3 hours ago. But i protest you shoulld use mine. Cause first of all my code is easier to read. And second of all i got higher votes meaning the community liked my anwser more. So personally i feel as i have deserved best anwser.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timeout that will run after 12 minutes and posts the form.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $(form).submit();},
   12 * 60 * 1000
);
```

Comment: Thank you, for this very SIMPLE solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` as shown below

```js
function time() {
    var time = 10 * 1;  // Replace 1 with 12
    var minutes, seconds;
    var myVar = setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(time / 60);
      seconds = parseInt(time % 60);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
       
      time--;
      
      if (time < 0) {
        //document.getElementById("myForm").submit();    //Submit your form here
        clearInterval(myVar);
        alert('Form is auto submitted');
      }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="time()">
  <!-- question code -->
<div id="time"></div><!-- show time  -->
</body>
```

Comment: Your code start counting (I am not sure if it is backward or forward) after displaying the alert. (Try running it). I will see how I can walk my way using this. Thanks for making it simple and well documented.

Comment: I know. But after the form is submitted, I think there is no point in counter going downwards. Although you can use `clearInterval()`. Check the updated snippet.

Comment: Better... I can work with this. Thanks a bunch